# What green tea has the highest caffeine content?

Tags: tea

How do these teas rank by caffeine content: Japanese dragon pearls, Matcha organic green tea, and gyokura imperial green tea? Is there any green tea with more than the ones in that list?

PS: Is it possible to get an antioxidant rating too? ie these teas rated by antioxidant levels, and if there are any other teas with stronger antioxidant levels, thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about flavor? Caffeine? Isn't there enough variation within each of those that no single one would be strongest, anyway?

Comment: clarification is about caffeine, thanks. Is there an order for these green teas, strongest to least among these teas, and if there is any other green tea stronger then any of these, info is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea about what the absolute strongest teas are, but all three of the things you mentioned appear to have caffeine and antioxidant ratings here: [Gyokuro Imperial Green Tea](http://www.teavana.com/the-teas/green-teas/p/gyokuro-imperial-green-tea) [Jasmine Dragon Phoenix Pearls Green Tea](http://www.teavana.com/the-teas/green-teas/p/jasmine-dragon-phoenix-pearls-green-tea) [Matcha Japanese Green Tea](http://www.teavana.com/the-teas/green-teas/p/matcha-japanese-green-tea)

I suppose that establishes a rough ordering - matcha is strong, the imperial green is next, and the pearls are last. But I'd take it all with big spoonful of salt; there's tons of variation even within a specific variety, and you can get lots of different kinds of matcha, lots of kinds of tea made into pearls, and so on.